# Converting JSON to CLOB in Mule 4 throws error

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am converting a Mule app from 3.9.5 to 4.4.1. I am trying to write a json response from an http request to a clob column in an oracle table  and getting an error

***cannot create a clob from a value of type 'class java.util.linkedhashmap'***

I tried to introduce a dataweave transformation as below but still receiving the same error above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<http:request method="GET" config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${http.path}/{report_id}" doc:name="Request" doc:id="e596773f-d948-47fb-9cee-c23cf1a4dfdc" >
                        <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
    ---
    {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer " ++ vars.accessToken,
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    }]]]></http:headers>
                <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
    ---
    {
        "report_id" : vars.expenseReportID
    }]]]></http:uri-params>
</http:request>
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="5d6cc3d7-0236-499a-9f93-1a2b2f331ae8">

<ee:message>

<ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0

output application/java

---

payload] ]></ee:set-payload>

</ee:message>

</ee:transform>

<db:insert doc:name="DB_Insert" doc:id="09010c0a-7a89-4d9c-926f-eaf7ac36b9da" config-ref="Database_Config">

<db:sql>INSERT INTO stg_clientesalesforce (id_carga, contenido_json)

VALUES (:id_carga, :contenido_json)</db:sql>

<db:input-parameters><![CDATA[# [{"id_carga" : 12,

"contenido_json": payload}]] ]></db:input-parameters>

</db:insert>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLOB is just a very large string (Character large object) so you just need to get your payload as string. You can use the [`write`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-write) function for this.

`payload write "application/json"`

Comment: Thanks @Harshank Bansal that did the trick.

Comment: The reason this conversion is required is that there is an implicit transformation in the db:input-parameters section.

Comment: @aled It will be transformed to `Object` at the HTTP Listener based on content type. If the `content-type` header said `text/plain` then probably no transformation would be needed.

Comment: And if the content type was text/plain, then I think the transformation to `output application/java --- payload` will also give a String. not a HashMap.

Comment: @HarshankBansal if the input JSON is a single string yes, if it is an object by default it will return a Java Map that contains the key-values. It is easy to test.

Comment: @aled It does not matter if the response body is a full JSON or a simple string. If the Response header `content-type` says `text/plain`, it will be read as a String and not JSON. And the transformation will also yield a String not a `Map`. Just tested it myself for confirmation and it is behaving like that

Comment: Also, for my first comment I meant that the payload will be transformed at `HTTP Request` not the `Listener`.

Comment: The content type is not in the question, so we can only guess or deduce it from the symptoms. If it would be `text/plain` yes it should convert to a string, but then it would not throw the error. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @aled OP mentioned that he is trying to convert JSON Response to CLOB. I am explaining that it is not happening because there is some implicit conversion in the db connector (as you mentioned in the comment). The `write` is required because the response is JSON.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you on that and yours is the right solution. What I'm saying is that the payload from the request could not have content type `text/plain`, because the call to `write()` would not be needed and OP would not have that error.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying too. lol.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a JSON because the application converts the response from the HTTP request to a Java object in the Transform component. That's also clear from the error message which shows the actual class (`class java.util.linkedhashmap` a HashMap). Removing the Transform completely may be enough to make it work.

Update: I missed that the transformation that was actually causing the error was the one inside `<db:input-parameters>` to convert the payload to a parameter. See @Harshank Bansal answer instead of this one.

Comment: Thanks @aled Initially I had no transformation and still got the same error message. I once again tried taking out the transformation but no luck same error.